# How to get message by message_token using Viber REST API?

Tags: rest, viber, viber-api

I'm building the Viber bot which will be served using different services. One of the problem is about getting the exact message which has been sent to the user.

The "received" event gives `message_token`, so I wonder if it's possible to use it in order to get the message.

Or I have to use my own mechanism of sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viber `message_token` is an identifier for peer-2-peer connection between Viber server and/or your local or online server and not the actual message. Moreover, there is no "buffer" for messages to be stored both locally or online. There is an internal process to store message when recipient is offline and then resend message when it is got online but I couldn't find direct access to them.

I did something similar by storing incoming messages to SQL using datetime (milliseconds) as timestamp in order to identify the message. However, you can combine Token also for knowing the session or to be more specific `user_ID`, both are unique.

Hope that helps to work around your problem...

Comment: Thank you!

After all, it turned out that Viber bot platform is pretty "avid" in terms of saving/extracting information compared to others. For example, Messenger bot platform also has some kind of "echo" events and they send you the full message user received.
But I guess it's just a side effect of their infastructure, where they don't save any messages already received by user.

I hope your answer will help others who face with the same issue :)